# What are the correct parameters for the linux list_for_each_entry() macro?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module

I'm working on an assignment where we have been asked to write a C Loadable Kernel Module that traverses the Linked List of active processes. My question is, what are the correct parameters for the `list_for_each_entry()` function? I've done research but I am still extremely confused.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <linux/module.h>  
#include <linux/kernel.h>       
#include <linux/sched.h>  
#include <linux/init_task.h>  

int processCount = 0;
struct task_struct *initTask = &init_task;

int init_module(void)
{

    printk(KERN_INFO "Jared Rathbun\n");
    
    
    struct task_struct *type;

    list_for_each_entry(type, struct task_struct, children)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Name: %-20s| PID: %-5d| State: %-4ld| Priority: %-5d| Policy: %-5d| Recent CPU: %-5d| Parent Name: %-20s| PPID: %-5d\n", type->comm, type->pid, type->state, 
        type->prio, type->policy, type->recent_used_cpu, type->parent->comm, type->parent->pid);
    } 
    
    /* Print the init process */
    printk(KERN_INFO "Init Process\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Name: %-20s| PID: %-5d| State: %-3ld| Priority: %-5d| Policy: %-5d| Recent CPU: %-5d| Parent Name: %-20s| PPID: %-5d\n", initTask->comm, initTask->pid, initTask->state, 
        initTask->prio, initTask->policy, initTask->recent_used_cpu, initTask->parent->comm, initTask->parent->pid);
    processCount++;
    
    /* Print the current process */
    printk(KERN_INFO "Current Process\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Name: %-20s| PID: %-5d| State: %-3ld| Priority: %-5d| Policy: %-5d| Recent CPU: %-5d| Parent Name: %-20s| PPID: %-5d\n", current->comm, current->pid, current->state, 
        current->prio, current->policy, current->recent_used_cpu, current->parent->comm, current->parent->pid);
    processCount++;
    
    printk(KERN_INFO "TOTAL PROCESS COUNT: %d\n", processCount);
    
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module( void )
{
    return;
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Kernel Module that traverse the list of running processes on the OS");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Jared Rathbun");
```

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I have fixed the parameters for list_for_each_entry, but now get the "Killed" message when inserting using insmod. Does anyone know what may cause this?

```
#include <linux/module.h>  
#include <linux/kernel.h>       
#include <linux/sched.h>  
#include <linux/init_task.h>  

struct task_struct *initTask = &init_task;
struct list_head *listHead;
struct task_struct *type;

int init_module(void)
{
    int processCount = 0;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Jared Rathbun\n");
    
    /* Print the init process */
    printk(KERN_INFO "Init Process\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Name: %-20s| PID: %-5d| State: %-3ld| Priority: %-5d| Policy: %-5d| Recent CPU: %-5d| Parent Name: %-20s| PPID: %-5d\n", initTask->comm, initTask->pid, initTask->state, 
        initTask->prio, initTask->policy, initTask->recent_used_cpu, initTask->parent->comm, initTask->parent->pid);
    processCount++;
    
    /* Traverse the Linked List of processes */
    
    list_for_each_entry(type, listHead, sibling)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Name: %-20s| PID: %-5d| State: %-4ld| Priority: %-5d| Policy: %-5d| Recent CPU: %-5d| Parent Name: %-20s| PPID: %-5d\n", type->comm, type->pid, type->state, 
        type->prio, type->policy, type->recent_used_cpu, type->parent->comm, type->parent->pid);
    } 
    
    /* Print the current process */
    printk(KERN_INFO "Current Process\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Name: %-20s| PID: %-5d| State: %-3ld| Priority: %-5d| Policy: %-5d| Recent CPU: %-5d| Parent Name: %-20s| PPID: %-5d\n", current->comm, current->pid, current->state, 
        current->prio, current->policy, current->recent_used_cpu, current->parent->comm, current->parent->pid);
    processCount++;
    
    printk(KERN_INFO "TOTAL PROCESS COUNT: %d\n", processCount);
    
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module( void )
{
    return;
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Kernel Module that traverse the list of running processes on the OS");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Jared Rathbun");
```

Comment: Have you searched other questions about [iterating processes](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+kernel+iterate+process+site:stackoverflow.com)? Have you checked e.g. [that] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862357/how-to-finding-all-runnable-processes) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55431226/c-linux-custom-kernel-module-to-iterate-over-a-process-children-blows-up-ke) questions? They both use `for_each_process` macro. If you wonder how this macro works, you may check its implementation: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.9.11/source/include/linux/sched.h#L2305

Comment: Please create a new question for the new problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/list.h#L594)

`list_for_each_entry()` — iterate over list of given type.
Arguments

- **@pos**: the type * to use as a loop cursor.
- **@head**: the head for your list.
- **@member**: the name of the list_head within the struct.

Example of use: `list_for_each_entry(pos, head, member);`.